# Legend only for one of two pies in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I made two pies: one is inside the other. I also want to make a legend but only for the inner circle. 
One more significant thing: the inner circle has only two labels, that repeated 5 times, so when I make a legend for both pies, I get something like "paid, free, paid, free, etc"

```
...
titles = ['Free', 'Paid']
subgroup_names= 5*titles
subgroup_size = final.num.tolist()

a, b, c = [plt.cm.Blues, plt.cm.Reds, plt.cm.Greens]
#Outer ring
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.axis('equal')
mypie, _ = ax.pie(group_size, radius = 2.5, labels = group_names,
                  colors = [a(0.7), a(0.6), a(0.5), a(0.4), a(0.3)])
plt.setp(mypie, width = 1, edgecolor = 'white')

#Inner ring
mypie2, _ = ax.pie(subgroup_size, radius = 1.6, labels = subgroup_names,
                   labeldistance = 0.7, colors = [b(0.5), c(0.5)])
plt.setp(mypie2, width = 0.8, edgecolor = 'white')

plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

Comment: Provide your data so that people can run your code. Put a complete, minimal, runnable code

Answer (score 1):

`plt.legend` accepts a list of handles and labels as parameters.  `get_legend_handles_labels()` conveniently gets a list of handles and of labels that would normally be used. Via list indexing you can grab the interesting part.

To center the labels inside the plot, the `textprops=` parameter of `plt.pie` accepts a horizontal and vertical alignment.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

titles = ['Free', 'Paid']
subgroup_names = 5 * titles
subgroup_size = np.random.uniform(10, 30, len(subgroup_names))
group_size = subgroup_size.reshape(5, 2).sum(axis=1)
group_names = [f'Group {l}' for l in 'abcde']

a, b, c = [plt.cm.Blues, plt.cm.Reds, plt.cm.Greens]
# Outer ring
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.axis('equal')
mypie, _ = ax.pie(group_size, radius=2.5, labels=group_names,
                  colors=[a(0.7), a(0.6), a(0.5), a(0.4), a(0.3)])
plt.setp(mypie, width=1, edgecolor='white')

# Inner ring
mypie2, _ = ax.pie(subgroup_size, radius=1.6, labels=subgroup_names,
                   labeldistance=0.7, colors=[b(0.5), c(0.5)],
                   textprops={'va': 'center', 'ha': 'center'})
plt.setp(mypie2, width=0.8, edgecolor='white')

handles, labels = plt.gca().get_legend_handles_labels()
labels_to_skip = len(group_names)
plt.legend(handles[labels_to_skip:labels_to_skip + 2], labels[labels_to_skip:labels_to_skip + 2])
plt.show()
```

[image: demo plot]

PS: To leave out the labels from the pie chart and only have them in the legend, call `plt.pie()` without the `labels=` parameter. And create the legend from the patches returned by `plt.pie()` (limited to the first two in this case):

```py
# Inner ring
mypie2, _ = ax.pie(subgroup_size, radius=1.6,
                   labeldistance=0.7, colors=[b(0.5), c(0.5)])
plt.setp(mypie2, width=0.8, edgecolor='white')
plt.legend(mypie2[:len(titles)], titles)
```

[image: labels only in the legend]

Comment: Thank You a lot! Everything works!
But is it possible to not show the labels on a pie?